# Find all uses of a class in an assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, nunit, il

Is it possible to find all uses of a class in an assembly?

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var numUsages = FindUsages(typeof(MyDeprecatedType),typeof(MyDeprecatedType).Assembly);
    Assert.LessOrEqual(expectedNumUsages, numUsages);
}

public static int FindUsages(Type type, Assembly assembly)
{
    return //Num usages of deprecated type
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://NDepend.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817473/how-to-use-c-sharp-to-find-usages-of-a-class-or-method

Comment: I don't Think you will be able to do this with Reflection alone. Mono.Cecil can probably do this. VS also has a Find References of tool (though this would not help the unit test usage scenario)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with reflection only by looking into metadata and interpret method body enable through methodbase.getmethodbody.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You can read method body like this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14058/Parsing-the-IL-of-a-Method-Body